# uib-typeahead, can't set ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `uib-typeahead` in my view.
I would like, when I enter the view, `uib-typehead` to point at the client I have selected previously and display it's name. I have `'[object Object]'` in my input instead.

Here is what I have done:

```
<input
   type="text"
   ng-model="vm.business.client"
   uib-typeahead="client as client.name for client in vm.clients | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
   class="form-control">
```

Comment: please paste your `vm.clients` object,

Comment: it's an array of objects [address, name, telephone, etc...]

Comment: So you have something like `vm.clients = [ {"adress": "...", "name":"..."}, {...} ];`?

Comment: you might be having an object inside the name key, can you paste the complete object?

Comment: the array is about 300 clients. i can post one sample but not the whole array : {"id":365,"name":"IBM","country":"USA","address":"blahblahblah","telephone":null}